# Let $a$ and $b$ be positive integers. Prove that $b$ divides $a$ iff $\gcd(a, b)=a$

Tags: abstract-algebra, euclidean-algorithm

Having trouble with this euclidean algebra proof!

Let $a$ and $b$ be positive integers. Prove that $b$ divides $a$ iff $\gcd(a, b)=a$

Comment: That's false, try $a=2, b=4$ for example.

Comment: Where did your trouble start? If you show us what you tried, we can help better. Also, please use MathJax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you mean $gcd(a,b)=b$. Let's denote $g\equiv gcd(a,b)$.

In the forward direction, if $b$ divides $a$, then since $b$ divides itself it is a common divisor, therefore $b \leq g$. But if $b < g$ then we get a contradiction since $g$ needs to divide $b$ so cannot be larger than $b$.

In the reverse direction, if $g=b$, then by definition of $gcd$ we have that  $b$ divides $a$.

Comment: More generally if $\,a\mid b\,$ then $\,d\mid a,b\iff d\mid a,\,$ so $\,a,b,$ and $\,a\,$ have the same set $S$ of common divisors $\,d,\,$ hence the same *greatest* common divisor (= max $S$), i.e. apply the [universal property charatcerizing the gcd](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3356212/242).