# $d\mid a,b \iff d\mid\gcd(a,b) \ $ [GCD Universal Property]

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

I know that the definition of gcd of two numbers $ a, b $ is $G$ ,where

$G\mid a$, $\;G\mid b  $ and

If $d\mid a$, $\;d\mid b $, then $ d\mid G.$

Now, using this how do I prove that in $\mathbb Z$, this definition coincides with the definition that $G$ is the GREATEST (w.r.t. usual ordering) common divisor?

So to prove that I write, say $G=dq+ r,\;  0\le r<d$. My aim is to show that $ r$ is $0$. So I have to construct some $G+x $ which is also a divisor of both $ a$ and $b$, to get a contradiction. How do I get $ x$?

Comment: It is the gretatest common divisor w.r.t. the partial order  $ x\prec y\iff x\mid y$.

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Well, by definition, $G\succ d$  for any common divisor of $a$ and $b$. Incidentally, $G\succ d$ implies $G\ge d$ for the usual ordering. I'm not sure this is  what you had in mind  with ‘elaborate’, though.

Comment: Except for zero.

Answer (score 2):

The definition says that the gcd $G$ is a common divisor that is *divisibly greatest*, i.e. if $\,d\,$ is any common divisor then $\,d\mid G,\,$ so $\, d\le G,\,$ thus $G$ is  a *greatest* common divisor.  Combining both directions we obtain the following handy *bidirectional* form of the general definition of a gcd

$$g\,\text{ is a gcd of }\,a,b\,\text{ in }R\ \ \text{ if }\ \  \bbox[5px,border:1px solid #c00]{d\mid a,b\iff d\mid g}\ \text{ holds for all}\ \ d\in R\qquad\qquad\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $$

Indeed putting $\,d=g\,$ in $(\Leftarrow)$ yields $\,g\mid a,b,\,$ so $\,g\,$ is a common divisor of $\,a,b,\,$  and necessarily  divisibly greatest since direction $(\Rightarrow)$ shows every common divisor $\,d\,$ divides $\,g.$

Below is a proof of the "divisibly greatest" form of the gcd in $\Bbb Z,\,$ via Bezout.

**Theorem** $\ \ \ \   d\mid a,b\iff d\mid (a,b)\ \ \ $ [[GCD Universal Property]](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3149/242)

${\bf Proof}\ \ (\Rightarrow)\ \ \ d\mid a,b\,\Rightarrow\, d\mid (a,b) = i\:\!a\!+\!j\:\!b,\, $ some $\, i,j\in\Bbb Z,\,$ by [Bezout.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/718833/242)

$(\Leftarrow)\ \ \ \ d\mid (a,b)\mid a,b\,\Rightarrow\, d\mid a,b\ $ by transitivity of $ $ "divides".

**Remark**  $\ $ Dually we have the universal property of LCM

**Lemma** $\ \ \ a,b\mid m\iff [a,b]\mid m\ \ \ $ [[LCM Universal Property]](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2038083/242)

In more general UFD's such as $\,\Bbb Z[x]\,$ and $\,\Bbb Q[x,y]\,$ there generally [is not a Bezout equation for gcds](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2357893/242) so the above proof of the gcd universal property fails. But instead use prime factorizations to prove the gcd universal property (then it boils down to the universal property of min & max on exponents of primes, e.g. [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/624222/242)).

---

**Or** we can prove the GCD Universal Property directly by induction on $\,\color{#90f}{{\rm size} := a\!+\!b}.\,$ It's clearly true if $\,a\!=\!0\,$ or $\,b\!=\!0,\,$ or if $\,a\! =\! b\!:\ c\mid a,a\!\iff\! c\mid (a,a)=a.\,$ Else $\,a\!\neq\! b\!\neq\!0.\,$ By symmetry, wlog $\,a>b.\,$  so $\, c\mid a,b\!\iff\! \color{#0a0}{c\mid a\!-\!b,b}\!\iff\! c\mid(a\!-\!b,b)=(a,b)\,$ since  $\,\color{#0a0}{\rm green}\,$ instance has smaller $\,\color{#90f}{{\rm size}} = (a\!-\!b)+b = a < \color{#90f}{a+b},\,$ so $\rm\color{}{induction}\,$ applies.