# How to prove that for every $i$, $a_i = i$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I am a beginner in number theory and I would like some hints to solve the following  problem :
Assume we have natural numbers $a_1,a_2,...$ such that $i$ is not equal to $j$ and $\gcd(a_i , a_j) = \gcd(i,j)$. Prove that $a_i = i$.
I know that I have to show $i$ counts $a_i$ and $a_i$ counts $i$ but I don’t know how to show this.
Since $\gcd(i,j) = \gcd(j,i)$ is it also true that $a_i = j$?

Comment: "*Based on the question I think it is also possible to say $a_i=j$*"  What is $j$ from $a_i$'s perspective?  $a_i$ knows nothing about $j$.  For instance, $\gcd(a_6,a_3)=\gcd(6,3)$ as well as $\gcd(a_6,a_8)=\gcd(6,8)$.  So, are you suggesting that $a_6 = 3$ is a possibility?  Or that $a_6 = 8$?  It can't simultaneously be both...

Comment: It should not be a possibility(as you also pointed out), I am saying I don’t know how the proof goes but as in gcd the order of elements does not matter (gcd(i,j) = gcd(j,i)) any proof we have for i would be true for j as well right ?

Comment: Certainly not...  We begin with "suppose that $n$ is a natural number.  We wish to prove that $a_n=n$.  To accomplish this consider...  yada yada... since $\gcd(a_n,a_x)=\gcd(n,x)$ we know that... yada yada... also since $\gcd(a_n,a_y)=\gcd(n,y)$ we also know that..."  Here, we can clearly keep track of which of the numbers was $n$ and won't confuse it with $x$ or $y$ since $n$ was the only one that appeared in both equations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, note that $a_i=i$ works.
Next, note that $i|a_i$ because $\gcd(a_i,a_{2i})=\gcd(i,2i)=i$
Now assume that for some $a_i,$ there is $k \gt 1$ such that $ a_i=ik$.  We know that $ik|a_{ik}$, so  $ik|\gcd(a_i,a_{ik})\neq \gcd(i,ik)$ is a contradiction, so there is no such $i$.

This fails if your sequence is not infinite.  If there are only $n$ terms in your sequence, you could multiply each term in the sequence by a different prime greater than $n$ and get a new sequence that worked.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $ $ [migrated from a [deleted thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3547214/242)]

$$\begin{align}\rm n\:\!\neq\, {\small 2}\:\!n\ \Rightarrow\  &\rm ({An},A\:\!{{\small 2}\:\!n}) =\:\! (n,\:\!2\:\!n)\:\!\Rightarrow \ \ \ \color{#c00}{n\mid{An}}\\[.3em]
 \rm n\neq An\ \Rightarrow\  &\rm \underbrace{(An,AAn)}_{\Large\color{#c00}{An}}\! = (n,An)\Rightarrow An\mid n\,\Rightarrow\, n = An  \end{align}\qquad$$

[Alternatively](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3562678/242) using the [gcd universal property](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3356212/242) $\ d\mid a,b\iff d\mid(a,b)\ $ we have

$$\begin{align} m\mid a_n &\iff m\mid\ a_m,\ a_n\ \ \ \ \, {\rm by}\ \ m\mid a_m\\
&\iff m\mid (a_m,a_m)\ \ \ \rm by\ \  gcd\ universal\ property\\
&\iff m\mid (m,n)\ \ \ \ \ \ \ {\rm by\ hypothesis, and}\ \ m\neq n\\
&\iff m\mid \, \ m,n \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \,\rm by\ \  gcd\ universal\ property\\
&\iff m\mid n 
\end{align}$$

So $a_n$ and $n$ have the same set $S$ of divisors $m$, so the same $\rm\color{#c00}{greatest}$ divisor $\, a_n = \color{#c00}{\max} S = n$