# Understanding the proof of Russian Olympic question

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation, contest-math, gcd-and-lcm

I was reading the book Putnam and Beyond. When I tried to calculate some examples, I came across one that I did not calculate, so I looked at the solution, but I did not understand it.

Here is the task:

> The sequence $a_1,\,a_2,\,a_3,\,...$ of positive integers satisfies $\gcd(a_m,a_n)=\gcd(m,n)$ for $m\neq n$. Prove that $a_n=n$ for all $n$.

Here is the solution:

> For any integer $m$, we have $\gcd(a_m,a_{2m})=\gcd(2m,m)=m$, and so $m$ divides $a_m$. Then, it follows that for any other integer $n$, $m$ divides $a_n$ if and only if it divides $\gcd(a_m,a_n)=\gcd(m,n)$. Thus $a_n$ has exactly the same divisors as $n$. Hence it must equal $n$, for all $n$.

More specifically, I did not understand the second and third sentences.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It seems that you are more interested in other proofs than the cited proof, so that makes your question a dupe. But if you want to understand the cited proof then see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have that $m|a_m$, another way to argue is
Assume there is $a_n$ with $a_n \neq n$.  Then $a_n=kn$ for some $k \gt 1$.  We also know $kn|a_{kn}$, which would give $\gcd(a_n,a_{kn})=kn \neq n$ as required so we have a contradiction.

Comment: I don't understand why gcd($a_n$, $a_{kn}$) must equal to $n$.

Comment: because $a_n=kn$ and $kn|a_{kn}$ from the first statement.

Comment: But that means that gcd($a_n$, $a_{kn}$) = kn, not n. Why is required n?

Comment: @TomášMacháček Because the problem condition requires that $\gcd(a_n,a_{kn})=\gcd(n,kn)=n.$

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The proof uses the [gcd universal property](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3356212/242) $\ d\mid a,b\iff d\mid(a,b)\ $ as follows

$$\begin{align} m\mid a_n &\iff m\mid\ a_m,\ a_n\ \ \ \ \, {\rm by}\ \ m\mid a_m\\
&\iff m\mid (a_m,a_m)\ \ \ \rm by\ \  gcd\ universal\ property\\
&\iff m\mid (m,n)\ \ \ \ \ \ \ {\rm by\ hypothesis, and}\ \ m\neq n\\
&\iff m\mid \, \ m,n \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \,\rm by\ \  gcd\ universal\ property\\
&\iff m\mid n 
\end{align}$$

So $a_n$ and $n$ have the same set $S$ of divisors $m$, so the same $\rm\color{#c00}{greatest}$ divisor $\, a_n = \color{#c00}{\max} S = n$

Comment: Thank you as well for the explanation.

Comment: @Tomáš The proof has the same form as [this common proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/192472/242) of the modular reduction step in the Euclidean algorithm.