# Prove $a^{\frac{\phi(mn)}2} \equiv 1\pmod {mn}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, totient-function

I want to show that given $\gcd(m,n)=1$ with $m,n \gt2$ and $\gcd(a, mn)=1$, then $a^{\frac{\phi(mn)}2} \equiv 1\pmod {mn}$, where $\phi(mn)$ is the Euler Totient function.

My approach started using Euler's theorem, given $\gcd(a, n)= 1$ then $ a^{\phi(n)} \equiv 1\pmod {n}$. And since $(m,n)=1$ then: $$a^{\phi(mn)} \equiv 1\pmod {mn}$$

I just cannot seem to get the $\frac12$ factor to appear. What I tried doing was just raising both sides to the $\frac 12$

$$a^{\phi(mn)} \equiv 1\pmod {mn} \Rightarrow a^{\frac{\phi(mn)}2} \equiv 1^{\frac12}\pmod {mn} \equiv 1\pmod{mn}$$
But I somehow feel this is wrong. So another way I tried was again with Euler's theorem:

$$a^{\phi(n)} \equiv 1\pmod {n} \Rightarrow (a^{\phi(m)})^{\phi(n)} \equiv 1\pmod {n} \Rightarrow a^{\phi(m)\phi(n)} \equiv 1\pmod {n} $$

$$a^{\phi(m)} \equiv 1\pmod {m} \Rightarrow (a^{\phi(n)})^{\phi(m)} \equiv 1\pmod {m} \Rightarrow a^{\phi(n)\phi(m)} \equiv 1\pmod {m} $$

Multiplying one by the other yields:

$$a^{2\phi(m)\phi(n)} \equiv 1\pmod {mn} \Rightarrow a^{2\phi(mn)} \equiv 1\pmod {mn}$$

Or using the CRT:

$$a^{\phi(m)\phi(n)} \equiv 1\pmod {mn} $$

From here I have no idea on where to go or what to try, I was thinking perhaps something related to Wilson's Theorem to make the $\frac12$ factor appear, but since m and n may not be prime, they are just coprime, I don't know if I can use that. Am I going in the right direction?

Comment: Please search to avoid addinge dupe questions, Here they can be quickly [located by approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24a%5E%7B%5Cfrac%7B%5Cphi%5Cleft(mn%5Cright)%7D%7B2%7D%7D%5Cequiv1%5Cpmod%5Cleft%5C%7Bmn%5Cright%5C%7D%24&p=2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint*: Prove that $\phi(N)$ is even for all $N\geq 3$.  So both $\phi(m),\phi(n)$ are even, hence you have the spare factor of 2: $\operatorname{lcm}(\phi(m),\phi(n))\mid \frac12\phi(m)\phi(n)$.

Comment: So since $\phi(mn)$ is always even I can divide by $2$ without any restrictions just because I have the spare factor of $2$?

Comment: No.  $\phi(m)$ divides $\phi(m)\frac{\phi(n)}{2}$ and $\phi(n)$ divides $\frac{\phi(m)}{2}\phi(n)$.  So $a^{\phi(m)\phi(n)/2}\equiv(a^{\phi(m)})^{\phi(n)/2}$ is $1$ mod $m$ and similarly mod $n$, and CRT gives the result.

Comment: Please strive not to add more dupe answers to FAQs. Here they can be quickly [located by approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24a%5E%7B%5Cfrac%7B%5Cphi%5Cleft(mn%5Cright)%7D%7B2%7D%7D%5Cequiv1%5Cpmod%5Cleft%5C%7Bmn%5Cright%5C%7D%24&p=2).

Comment: @BillDubuque $m,n$ not primes and all results seems to be asking for prime case (or question 3491175 with 3n and 9n a very specific version)?

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3433521/242) in the linked dupe (there are also many other dupes - it's a FAQ).