# Let $R$ be an integral domain and $r, s$ $\in$ $R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, gcd-and-lcm, integral-domain

Let *R* be an integral domain and *r, s* $\in$ *R*.

I know that an integral domain is a commutative ring with identity that has no zero-divisors. Hence, *R* is a commutative ring with identity and has no zero-divisors.

Given this, can the gcd(*r*, *s*) have more than one gcd? Also, would the gcd(*r*, *s*) be associates of one another?

I am trying to work this out in $\mathbb{Z}$[$x$] (since I know that $\mathbb{Z}$ is an integral domain as $\mathbb{Z}$[$x$] is a commutative polynomial ring with identity that has no zero-divisors) but I do not know if this is a smart integral domain to work with. Would appreciate some guidance. Thanks in advance

Comment: What you are looking for is called a GCD domain https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GCD_domain

In particular for your example, since $\mathbb{Z}$ is a UFD, $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is also a UFD. Therefore, $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is a GCD domain based on the inclusion chart in the link.

Comment: @take008 Since $\mathbb{Z}$[$x$] is a GCD domain, does that mean that gcd(*r*, *s*) has more than one gcd and thus the gcd(*r*, *s*) are all associates of one another?

Comment: Depends on how you are defining $\gcd$. But in the most common definition, yes the $\gcd$ is unique up to units in GCD domains.

Comment: @take008 Thanks for the feedback!! So would the gcd's of (*r*, *s*) be associates of one another?

Comment: Let's do this from the definition. "There exists a unique minimal principal ideal $I$ containing the ideal generated by the two elements $r$, $s$." Suppose $a,b\in I$ both generated $I$: $(a)=(b)$. Then $a\in (b)$, so that $a=cb$. Similarly, $da=b$ for some $c,d\in R$. Therefore $a=cda$ and hence $cd=1$ by cancellation law and stuff. So, $c,d$ are units. So yes, they are associates.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: if $\,d_1,d_2$ are gcds then [by definition](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3356212/242)  $\, c\mid d_1\!\iff c\mid a,b\iff c\mid d_2\,$ so $\,\color{#c00}{d_1\mid d_2\mid d_1}$

**Beware** $ $ In rings that are not domains $\rm\color{#c00}{associates}$ [need not be a unit multiples.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3356212/242)