# Prove $\,\gcd(a,b)\mid {\rm lcm}(a,b)\ $

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, gcd-and-lcm

I have a hard time with this question, can someone explain?

"Prove that for any number $a$ and $b$, $(a,b)$ goes into $\text{lcm}(a;b)$"

Comment: "Explain this proof"... Where is the proof ?

Comment: I'm fairly sure this is a dupe but I couldn't locate one (yet).

Answer (score 2):

Hint: by [gcd & lcm universal property](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3356212/242) $\,\gcd(a,b)\mid a\mid {\rm lcm}(a,b)\,$ so by *transitivity* of divisibility ...

**Remark** $ $  The same argument works for any number of arguments to gcd & lcm. The hint boils down to $\,\inf S \le \sup S\,$ in poset / lattice language. More generally, the hint shows that *every* common divisor of a set of integers divides *every* common multiple.

Comment: Note: $\ x\mid y\ $ means $x$ divides $y\ $ (standard notation in number theory). $\ \ $